# can i use normal javascript code if in that code imported some module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

So in my code it gives me error FunctionOfMainJs is not defined which is function made of main.js so what can i do for run normal js code and also use import in same file

main.js

```
import {CreateDropDown} from "./asset/js/customdropdown.js";

new CreateDropDown([{"ImagePath":null,"OptionValue":"text1"}],"Container");

function FunctionOfMainJs(){
    alert("hey guys");
}

FunctionOfMainJs();
```

Comment: Your code as posted would work, so it's not clear what your question is about.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `FunctionOfMainJs`? The code you’ve shown works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call this function in another .js file? If so you will need to export the function:

`module.exports = {FunctionOfMainJS}`

Comment: yes i have been done it already

Comment: There is no `module.exports` in ECMAScript modules.

Comment: FunctionOfMainJS is a function which i want to use as normal function not as module function